# Reading XML dataframe with limited node roots in R

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file which contains archived text from the New Yorker magazine. I am new to analyzing XML, but I'm hoping to convert this file into a dataframe in R where I can do some basic text analyses (e.g., a word cloud).

This is a subset of the XML file:

```
<DjVuXML>
<HEAD>file://clustershare/storage/djvu/Conde%20Nast/New%20Yorker/1925_02_21/page0000004.djvu</HEAD>
<BODY>
<OBJECT data="file://clustershare/storage/djvu/Conde%20Nast/New%20Yorker/1925_02_21/page0000004.djvu" type="image/x.djvu" height="7080" width="5040" usemap="page0000004.djvu" >
<PARAM name="DPI" value="600" />
<PARAM name="GAMMA" value="2.200000" />
  <HIDDENTEXT>
    <PAGECOLUMN>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="742,420,776,362">2</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="738,631,934,562">weeks,</WORD>
            <WORD coords="969,638,1081,584">you</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1119,620,1244,564">will</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1281,641,1553,565">probably</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1589,624,1734,567">need</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1771,624,1878,589">one</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1916,642,1988,568">by</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="738,702,858,646">that</WORD>
            <WORD coords="899,703,1036,647">time</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1076,723,1334,649">anyhow.</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="819,871,966,814">This</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1014,872,1127,828">two</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1175,873,1374,817">week&apos;s</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1422,891,1588,817">delay</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1634,876,1811,819">looms</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1859,876,1911,841">as</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1958,877,1988,842">a</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="737,956,1099,900">tremendous</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1157,958,1395,900">obstacle</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1455,959,1566,904">and</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1623,977,1735,925">you</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1794,962,1984,904">hasten</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="736,1060,1101,983">breathlessly</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1128,1042,1186,1000">to</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1214,1042,1310,987">the</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1338,1063,1642,986">telephone</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1670,1065,1988,990">company&apos;s</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="736,1124,890,1070">office</WORD>
            <WORD coords="949,1125,1137,1070">where</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1194,1145,1307,1091">you</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1365,1128,1594,1071">become</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1650,1148,1774,1087">part</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1832,1128,1902,1073">of</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1958,1128,1988,1094">a</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="737,1225,946,1153">throng</WORD>
            <WORD coords="973,1229,1352,1155">surrounding</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1380,1212,1407,1178">a</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1436,1213,1669,1171">counter</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1698,1214,1795,1157">for</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1823,1214,1984,1160">about</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="735,1293,805,1259">an</WORD>
            <WORD coords="838,1296,999,1239">hour.</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1074,1296,1150,1240">At</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1183,1296,1278,1241">the</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1311,1297,1424,1240">end</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1455,1297,1526,1241">of</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1556,1297,1676,1242">that</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1709,1298,1846,1242">time</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1875,1316,1984,1262">you</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="736,1378,840,1322">tell</WORD>
            <WORD coords="871,1398,1013,1343">your</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1044,1398,1194,1337">story</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1225,1380,1282,1337">to</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1316,1381,1343,1346">a</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1375,1381,1504,1346">man</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1538,1381,1591,1340">at</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1625,1381,1721,1326">the</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1755,1382,1984,1339">counter</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="735,1463,865,1408">who</WORD>
            <WORD coords="916,1481,1125,1407">dodges</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1172,1464,1231,1421">to</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1279,1464,1308,1429">a</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1358,1465,1488,1409">desk</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1535,1484,1839,1410">telephone</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1890,1467,1984,1411">for</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="736,1548,1173,1493">conversational</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1203,1570,1465,1514">purposes</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1494,1569,1660,1515">every</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1688,1569,1848,1495">forty</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1875,1550,1986,1516">sec-</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="743,1632,777,1598">o</WORD>
            <WORD coords="802,1633,838,1599">n</WORD>
            <WORD coords="864,1633,901,1578">d</WORD>
            <WORD coords="926,1647,987,1599">s,</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1044,1652,1336,1577">obviously</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1387,1635,1446,1592">&#10;o</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="742,1720,1117,1664">demonstrate</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1189,1720,1340,1665">what</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1414,1720,1441,1686">a</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="743,1823,924,1748">really</WORD>
            <WORD coords="963,1820,1116,1761">great</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1158,1823,1294,1748">help</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1335,1805,1446,1749">this</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="744,1889,1039,1833">invention</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1077,1889,1119,1834">is</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1154,1889,1212,1848">to</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1247,1890,1274,1855">a</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1310,1907,1446,1833">busy</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="742,1974,893,1938">man.</WORD>
            <WORD coords="943,1974,1092,1917">This</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1119,1990,1446,1918">gentleman</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="744,2077,1067,2001">ultimately</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1120,2077,1280,2003">helps</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1333,2077,1446,2024">YOll</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="745,2142,833,2085">fill</WORD>
            <WORD coords="860,2142,958,2100">out</WORD>
            <WORD coords="985,2143,1054,2108">an</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1081,2163,1446,2087">Application</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="743,2226,840,2170">for</WORD>
            <WORD coords="870,2226,1088,2171">Service</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1118,2227,1307,2172">which</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1332,2246,1445,2192">you</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="744,2327,1040,2254">recognize</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1093,2311,1146,2276">as</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1197,2311,1293,2256">the</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1344,2312,1446,2256">old</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="745,2395,965,2338">income</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1000,2396,1088,2355">tax</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1123,2396,1315,2340">blanks</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1349,2397,1446,2341">the</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="745,2481,1139,2422">Government</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1196,2481,1330,2426">used</WORD>
            <WORD coords="1385,2482,1444,2425">in</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="754,2565,928,2511">1919.</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="4003,3841,4153,3784">THE</WORD>
            <WORD coords="4187,3842,4346,3787">NEW</WORD>
            <WORD coords="4377,3843,4636,3787">YORKER</WORD>
          </LINE>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="3383,6199,3583,6142">brands</WORD>
            <WORD coords="3612,6200,3681,6144">of</WORD>
            <WORD coords="3711,6202,3938,6144">hokum.</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="3405,4362,3776,4291">&#10;cJ</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="3382,6548,3656,6332">1-&amp;</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="4188,6542,4630,6292">-</WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
      <REGION>
        <PARAGRAPH>
          <LINE>
            <WORD coords="3818,6536,4059,6430">&#10; </WORD>
          </LINE>
        </PARAGRAPH>
      </REGION>
    </PAGECOLUMN>
  </HIDDENTEXT>
</OBJECT>
<MAP name="page0000004.djvu"/>
</BODY>
</DjVuXML>
```

I've had a lot of trouble extracting the text from this file in a delimited format. For example, using the XML package, I've tried the following approach:

```
filename<- "~/Desktop/New Yorker/1925_02_21/xml/page0000004.xml"
xmlData<-xmlParse(filename)
xmlDataFrame<-xmlToDataFrame(xmlData)
xmlDataFrame$OBJECT[2]
```

But this will just yield a long string of text with no spaces.

I have also tried to search for specific nodes within the XML file:

```
rootnode <- xmlRoot(xmlData)
print(rootnode[[2]][[1]])
```

But this will only return the entire xml file rather than specific nodes.

I know that I'm probably missing a really simple step for converting this into a manageable and analyzable dataframe. I'm happy to edit the question or provide more information if that would be helpful. As I mentioned, I'm a novice here so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `xml2` package. Assuming that your XML file is saved to the path `~/Desktop/New Yorker/1925_02_21/xml/page0000004.xml`:

```
library(xml2)
doc = read_xml("~/Desktop/New Yorker/1925_02_21/xml/page0000004.xml")
word_nodes = xml_find_all(doc, xpath = "//WORD")
extracted_text = paste(xml_text(word_nodes), collapse = " ")
```

The `xml_find_all` code uses Xpath, which is analogous to regular expressions but for trees. `"//WORD"` finds all `WORD` elements no matter where they are in the document. See [this W3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for more information.

The above code returns the following:

```
> extracted_text 
[1] "2 weeks, you will probably need one by that time anyhow. This two week's delay looms as a tremendous obstacle and you hasten breathlessly to the telephone company's office where you become part of a throng surrounding a counter for about an hour. At the end of that time you tell your story to a man at the counter who dodges to a desk telephone for conversational purposes every forty sec- o n d s, obviously \no demonstrate what a really great help this invention is to a busy man. This gentleman ultimately helps YOll fill out an Application for Service which you recognize as the old income tax blanks the Government used in 1919. THE NEW YORKER brands of hokum. \ncJ 1-& - \n "
```